# How do I move the clock in GNOME Classic?

Tags: gnome, clock

The clock in the middle is driving me batty and I can't get it to move to the right side of the screen where I would like it. No other log in works for me except GNOME Classic so I'm sticking with that--unfortunately, that means that none of the GNOME 3 extensions I've installed fix this issue.

There's no option to unlock or move if I right click it :( How can I move this thing??

Comment: See also this Question for further information on Gnome Classic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Comment: Good question this was bugging me as well. Whoever decided upon this Alt+Rightclick feature should be shot in the knees. I mean seriously, how unintuitive CAN you make things??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> (or <kbd>Windows/Super/Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> depending on your configuration) and right click the clock. Then you can access the panel menu for it (move/remove).

The same is true for adding widgets, creating new panels, etc.

Comment: None of the shortcuts work for me on gnome-shell 3.6 running Ubuntu 13.04. Any tips?