# How to add panel applets to classic gnome panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-classic

Because of Unity's inability to use *any* Gnome panel applets, I changed back to the classic gnome panel.

However, even in the classic interface, I'm finding I can't right-click the Gnome panel to change anything.

How do you add applets to the Gnome panel in the classic interface?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and Right Click. I had the exact same problem actually, but more with the clock in the middle of the screen driving me batty. :)

See: [How do I move the clock in GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65873/how-do-i-move-the-clock-in-gnome-classic)

If you are using gnome-classic (with effects), you actually have to hold <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right Click.

Comment: Why isn't this working for me?  I just downloaded 12.04, and I cannot add anything to the panel.  I've tried all the click combinations I know of :(

Comment: For those who don't know, "meta" is another name for the "Windows" key.

Comment: Remember to disable the annotates via CCSM otherwise the keycombo will not work