# How do I add program icons to the top bar in Gnome Classic Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gnome, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add panel applets to classic gnome panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66414/how-to-add-panel-applets-to-classic-gnome-panel)

I used to add items to the top bar in Ubuntu 10.04 by right clicking on the menu item.   Now that I am using 12.04 with the Gnome Classic menu, when I right click on a program from the menu, I don't get an option to add the program to the top bar, the program just starts.   How can I icons to the top bar in 12.04 Gnome Classic  that is as quick and simple a method as before?

Comment: The "secret" key combination is described by the answer now in your question.  As such, I've closed your question as a duplicate.  Thanks.