# Going back to Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic, lts

I want to know if I can go back to a 10.04 style Gnome environment. By 10.04 environment, I mean the ability to add icons and little applets, like drawer, on the top menu bar. Right now, after all I have tried, it does not seem possible. So, I am not stuck on using 10.04, but am using 10.04 as an example of things I liked and am wondering how to get them back.

Is this a straightforward thing to do, or more painful than it is worth?

If I go back to Gnome, am I going to suffer on the next LTS upgrade?

Right now, I have the basic 12.04 environment, with Gnome installed -- sudo apt-get install gnome-panel -- but I found I could not go back up to the top menu and put in my familiar drawers and other installed icons.

I tried both Gnome settings, one less graphically intensive than the other. As a matter of fact, Unity seemed to be better just because I could get to the few installed icons that the upgrade picked off my old Gnome menu.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66414/how-to-add-panel-applets-to-classic-gnome-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want go back to a 10.04 style Gnome environment, i think best solution for you is installing ["MATE desktop environment"](http://mate-desktop.org/) on Ubuntu 12.04.

You can find how you can do it from [this](http://mate-desktop.org/install/#ubuntu) link.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

after installing you need to logout and Then from login screen you can choose the session   . see image

[image]

But this won't likely be available forever, as it's a fallback session.

Comment: I've edited the original post. I'm not stuck on 10.04. I'm just wondering if there is a menu bar that will allow editing, like in 10.04, and there appears not to be, other than the side bar. At least now, with fiddling, I can get that to hide.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus try what i have given my friend . I am sure that will allow you to do so .

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback

Comment: The OP has already attemped to use the fallback session